# PHP - Mysql order data 123 like 132

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Mysql database like this

```
id     name 
1      very big
2      very big
3      big
4      big
5      small
6      small
```

i wanna order my database like this

```
id     name 
1      very big
3      big
5      small
6      small
4      big
2      very big
```

or like this :

```
id     name 
2      very big
4      big
6      small
5      small
3      big
1      very big



(indeed sorting from 123456 to 135642 )
```

how can i do it with php or mysql?

Comment: add a sort column to the db

Comment: I think there is no point in changing order of rows in db. All are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
 order by id % 2,
          (case when id % 2 = 0 then id end) asc
          id desc;
```